# How do I fill an empty div with js?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, django-templates

The aim is to access a particular endpoint after performing a search only when I hit a button but I am finding it difficult to do that with JS. I have an HTML which is rendered in an `html` endpoint, and I want that html file to fill an empty `div` I created in another HTML file. I am trying to achieve this with vanilla JS but all answers I see are in `JQuery` and I do not really know JS

## Implement search for friends.

```
def results(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    search_query = request.GET.get("username")
    searched_user = UserProfile.objects.filter(
            user__username__contains=search_query
        )
    return render(
    request, "toggle.html", {
        "searched_user":searched_user
    })
else:
    return HttpResponse("Search returned nothing")
```

`rendering html to fill empty div`

```
def html(request): 
return render(request, 
    template_name= "search_results.html"
)
```

`index.html`

```
 <p>Welcome</p>
<form id="search" method="GET" action="{% url 'results' %}" placeholder= "Search for user" 
 autocomplete="off">
{{form}}
<input type="submit" value="search" name="search">
</form>
```

`search_results.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block  spotify %}

 {%if searched_user %}
{% for each_searched_user in searched_user %}
<br/>{% for liked_songs in each_searched_user.liked_songs.all %}{{liked_songs}}<br/>
                        {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

`toggle.html`

```
 {% extends "base.html" %}
 {% block  spotify %}


 <div id="div">

 </div>

  <button id=likedsongsbutton>View liked songs</button>
  <script>
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', '{% url "html" %}', true);
   request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
    // Success!
    var resp = this.response;
    document.querySelector("#likedsongsbutton").addEventListener("click", 
       () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = resp
    })}}; 
 </script>

 {% endblock %}
```

so I am trying to fill the empty `div` in `toggle.html` using the `html` endpoint only when i hit the `likedsongsbutton`. Hitting the button does nothing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this script instead of above

```
<script>
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    var resp = request.responseText;
 // here as your response is string.

 
document.querySelector("#likedsongsbutton").addEventListener("click", 
   () => {document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = resp
  })}}; 
  }
 };
 request.open('GET', '{% url "html" %}', true);

 </script>
```

Comment: Button is unresponsive still.

Comment: add console.log(resp) and see whether the data is coming in console or not

Comment: Nothing shows. Why have you assigned `resp` when we have not visited the `html/` yet? `html/` returns the template I want in the `<div>`

Comment: is the response coming?